# Interface in UE5 not casting or working as a variable

Tags: unreal, unreal-5, interface

In UE5.3.2, I have created an interface in C++ (code at the end) that I'm trying to implement in a Blueprint. The editor gets the type correctly, and I have been able to make a simple implementation:

[image]

The implementation is a blueprint `Object` named `GoldCpp`. However, I can't use this type or I can't cast it:

[image]
[image]

The cast always fails (and prints false), and the "default value" for the `ItemInterface` shows no options. What am I missing?

```cpp
// This class does not need to be modified.
UINTERFACE(MinimalAPI, Blueprintable)
class UItemInterface : public UInterface
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
};

/**
 * 
 */
class LASTWORLD_API IItemInterface
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

    // Add interface functions to this class. This is the class that will be inherited to implement this interface.
public:
  UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, BlueprintImplementableEvent)
    UStaticMesh * GetMesh();
};
```